# Problem while navigating a statically generated site with nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm building a static site with nuxt but some elements are not static. In dev mode everything works without problems and gives me no error while after the generation, launching the `nuxt start` command, it gives me the following message: `TypeError: n.setAttribute is not a function` and `TypeError: can't access property "_isDestroyed`, and is undefined "only on a page and specifically when I click on one of the links in it. Anyone have any idea what it can be?

[image: console with error]

---

```js
require('dotenv').config()
export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',
  /**
   * Disable Purge CSS in prod
   */
  purgeCSS: {
    mode: 'postcss',
    enabled: false
  },
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'site title',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/custom.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/style.css' }
    ]
  },
  // Generate
  generate: {
    // 404 fallback
    fallback: true
  },
  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vuejs-paginate.js',
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-announcer.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-video', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/search-bar.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/search-view.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // Tailwind CSS
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    // Add page in sitemap route array
    '@/modules/sitemapRouteGenerator',
    // dotenv
    ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', {
      filename: '.env'
    }]
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    ['nuxt-i18n', {
      detectBrowserLanguage: {
        alwaysRedirect: false
      },
      strategy: 'prefix',
      defaultLocale: 'en',
      locales: [
        {
          code: 'en',
          iso: 'en-US',
          file: 'en.js',
          dir: 'ltr'
        },
        {
          code: 'it',
          iso: 'it-IT',
          file: 'it.js',
          dir: 'ltr'
        }
      ],
      langDir: 'locales/',
      vueI18n: {
        fallbackLocale: 'en'
      }
    }],
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // Always leave as last
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap'
  ],

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    ssr: true,
    extractCSS: true
  },
  // Axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost'
  },
  sitemap: {
    path: '/sitemap.xml',
    hostname: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    defaults: {
      changefreq: 'monthly',
      priority: 1.0,
      lastmod: new Date()
    },
    gzip: true,
    exclude: []
  }
}
```

---

The errors come from a page that dynamically generates all part of the detail.
Let me explain: I have a **Category** folder and inside it I have a `_slug.vue` file that I use to generate the main page of each category.
Inside the category folder I have an additional folder called **d**, which contains a `_detail.vue` file, which contains the article detail.
`_slug.vue` and _detail.vue are pages whose only different thing is the path, which is generated, and the fact that in `_slug` there is by default the first article and the list of articles that are part of that category while in `_detail` there is the article I select from the list.
The list is a

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a> article title</a
  </li>
</ul>
```

Initially I tried to use `<n-link>` to the `<a>` tag post but on click it only changed the path and did not redirect me to the page with the updated content.

Comment: Can you add some properly formatted and highlighted `nuxt.config.js` to your question? Also, how do you build your app? Also, from which files are those errors coming from? And, how do you navigate in your app?

Comment: My [nuxt config](https://appp.me/T7DWqm).
I generate the app using `nuxt generate` and test it using `nuxt start`

Comment: I've edited the nuxt condig **into** your question as text. You don't need to use `dotenv` in `nuxt.config.js`, this is already baked in. The rest of the configuration looks fine. Same for the build process. My 2 remaining questions still stand. Also, I guess that we will need to have a hosted [repro] pretty soon because this may come from your code (pages/components).

Comment: Hey, feel free to update your question to further answer me (just tell me that this was updated), this will be cleaner and you will not create a non-answer. I kinda get the thing. Still, my 2 initial questions (first comment) are valid. And I'd really appreciate some visuals of your structure or better, a [repro].

Comment: It seems to have solved it. I was injecting, through `v-html`, some content into a `p` tag and this caused me problems. After some testing I changed the `p` tag to `span` and it seems the errors are gone. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I've added an answer with some additional important part with your code. Also, to prevent further issues like this, I highly recommend to use ESlint for immediate debugging tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad that your code is now working!
I'd still recommend you to use [vue-dompurify-html](https://github.com/LeSuisse/vue-dompurify-html) to prevent any security issue, as explained in the official documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

The end result will not be a big change code-wise but it will be safer in terms of security.

```html
<div v-dompurify-html="rawHtml"></div>
```